# namespace problem migrating Reports & Dashboard

Tags: reporting, deployment, dashboard, custom-report-type, namespace

I have a problem moving Reports & Dashboard from my Dev Org to Production Org which has ***"Different Namespace"***. If deployed with eclipse it reports Error of namespace.

Source Org:- DEV Org
Destination Org :- Production Org (new namespace)

What can I do ?